# Regex as an input through console

Tags: java, regex

I need to get the regex expression from the user and assign it to a variable. Regex will not be hard coded in the code. How to achieve this. I'm using JOption dialog and it is not working. Is there any other way?

Currently this works.

```
            patternToMatch =   "^ABC.*XY\\\\16$";      
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patternToMatch);
```

and this doesnt work.

```
            patternToMatch = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Regex Term");
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patternToMatch);

Input = ^ABC.*XY\\\\16$ // Not Working
Input= "^ABC.*XY\\\\16$" //Not Working
```

Edited: Sorry. Not an object. Its a variable

Comment: Show us how you are trying to assign the regex to an object.

Comment: Are you entering the regex with double quotes?. Show us what you have given as input?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java `\\` is an escape-sequence for `\`. So, the actual value of string literal `"^ABC.*XY\\\\16$"` is `"^ABC.*XY\\16$"`. Check out what `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "^ABC.*XY\\\\16$");` displays.

To quote from Java Language Specification [3.10.6 "Escape Sequences for Character and String Literals"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6):

```
\ \     /* \u005c: backslash \ */
```

So, you should input `"^ABC.*XY\\16$"` in your dialog for this regex to work properly.

Comment: You only have to escape *literals*,  Since he is *accepting* a value from the standard input, he doesn't have to escape them by using additional backslashes.